# Как имитировать браузер и забрать значение параметров отправленных в POST

Tags: php

Есть сторонний сайт. Логика сайта такова: вводим в поле ввода номер, нажимаем "Получить информацию".
Далее идет редирект на страницу типа: `site.ru/num/введенный_номер`

На этой странице выполняется javascript код сайта, который генерирует значение параметра **trackingId** и отправляет POST запрос на API с этим сгенерированным параметром.

Пытался разобраться как генерируется **trackingId** , но бесполезно, JS код у них специально запутан.

Вопрос. Как имитировать через php как будто бы зашел через браузер, выполнился их JS код и отловить отправленные параметры на API?

P.S. кому интересно - ссылка на страницу на которой генерируется trackingId - [ссылка](http://parcelsapp.com/tracking/RA655050135RU)

Comment: Вы можете отключить дебагер такими настройками http://joxi.ru/p274P11TK9vjXA и дальше уже смотреть что за POST запросы сайт отправляет

Comment: @ДмитрийГорный я так уже делал. Какой запрос отправляет сайт я знаю. Дело в том что на основе введенного номера их JavaScript код генерирует `trackingId` - как он генирируется я не понял. поэтому решил что проше имитировать браузер чтобы выполнился из JS код и отловить trackingId

Comment: @iKey Не могу даже отдебажить, всё ужасно виснет. Где нарыл этот сайт? Кинь пример отправляемых данных)

Comment: @Владислав, там вот такие параметры генерирует их скрипт: trackingId=2f221q1l1l1h1r1n1j1n1m2h2i&carrier=Auto-Detect&language=ru&country=Belarus&platform=web-desktop&timestamp=1562238946330&wd=false&c=false&p=4&l=6, эти параметры передаётся POST на parcelsapp.com/api/v2/parcels, их скрипт генерирует trackingId да там все виснет при дебаге, они так специально сделали(

Comment: Я выяснил что **trackingId** генерирует именно их Javascript код и потом делает post

Comment: @iKey Исходный код страницы, внизу второй скрипт, если не ошибаюсь, на `cdn` лежит. Открываешь, делаешь деминимизацию. Ищешь обработчик на форму, а дальше по коду... Сложно правда будет, имена переменных запутаны. Дошёл до обработки, дальше моих познаний в js не хватает)

Comment: @Владислав, вот и я дошёл до туда и все((